# Use of undeclared identifier when calling method

Tags: objective-c

I'm beginning to program in objective-c.
I am getting a compiler error `Use of undeclared identifier when calling method`.

Header file:

```
//ViewController.h
typedef enum direction {north, south, west, east} Direction;
- (int)TurnRadius:(Direction) currentDirection:(Direction)intendedDirection;
```

Implementation file:

```
//ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
- (int)TurnRadius:(Direction) currentDirection : (Direction) intendedDirection {
    //Irrelevant implementation details
}

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    [TurnRadius north west]; //ERROR IS HERE
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the instance methods using self.

Replace your method invoking statement as below

```
[self TurnRadius:north :west];
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot colons.

```
[TurnRadius:north:west];
```

**EDIT:** Mahi is correct, you also need to call the method from `self` (the current object)

```
[self TurnRadius:north:west];
```